# Is this approach to insert/edit of Core Data nested objects the most efficient?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have the following Core Data model (simplified for example):

```
Person
  ->Address
    City
      >Region
        RegionName
      >Country
        CountryName
```

When a new Person is created

```
NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel=[[AppCoreData sharedInstance]objectModel];
NSEntityDescription *entity=[[objectModel entitiesByName] valueForKey:@"Beverage"];
Person *person=(Person*)[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

a Person entity is created w/o inserting into the object context so it is easy to abandon the insert if necessary.

Then the user can select a Region which may or may not exist in the database. A search is performed to see if the Region exists

```
  NSEntityDescription *entityDescription=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Region" inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:entityDescription];
  request.returnsObjectsAsFaults=NO;
  NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",region.id];
  [request setPredicate:predicate];

  NSError *error=nil;
  NSArray *array= [self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

  if ([array count] == 1) {
    //use existing object
    person.region=(Region*)[array objectAtIndex:0];
  } else {
    //create new object
    NSEntityDescription *entity=[[objectModel entitiesByName] valueForKey:@"Region"];
    self.collectionItem.beverage.region=(Region*)[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
    person.region.id=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[regionID intValue]];
    person.region.regionName=regionName;
  }
```

Finally, if the user does not abandon the insert, the person object is inserted into the object context and saved

```
[self.objectContext insertObject:self.collectionItem];
```

What is the best approach to dealing with nested Core Data objects where the nested objects, e.g., Region may or may not exist in Core Data? Examples or references appreciated.